# Forcing UIViewController in Landscape

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a UITabBar. In the first tab, I have a UINavigationController. Within that navigation controller, after a couple of UIVIewController are pushed onto the stack, there's a UIViewController in which the user can use their finger to sign.

I want this to be in Landscape mode. How can I force my the phone to turn into landscape? In that signature view controller, I implement supported orentiations function and return landscape right but still nothing happens.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tab bar controllers support a portrait
>   orientation by default and do not
>   rotate to a landscape orientation
>   unless all of the root view
>   controllers support such an
>   orientation.

So sayeth [Tab Bar Controllers and View Orientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW26).